# C# - Smartsheet - GetColumn() method data into class list

Tags: c#, json, smartsheet-api, smartsheet-c#-sdk-v2, smartsheet-c#-sdk-v1

I have the following class built out

```
public class DiscColConfig
{
    public long id { get; set; }
    public int index { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public List<string> options { get; set; }
    public bool locked { get; set; }
    public bool lockedForUser { get; set; }
    public bool validation { get; set; }
    public int width { get; set; }
}
```

this will be used to store the deserialized json results from the following method:

```
public static AreaColConfig GetAreaColConfig(long sid, long cid, SmartsheetClient ss)
{
        Column config = ss.SheetResources.ColumnResources.GetColumn(
        sid,
        cid,
        null
        );
        string json = config.ToString();
        AreaColConfig result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AreaColConfig>
        (json);
        return result;
}
```

how should i properly call `config`'s result into a string variable to deserialize into the class for storage?

If there is any additional information that would help let me know - first time running into smartsheet and its not playing very nice -_-

Answer (score 0):

Not a C# expert, but was able to get what you're looking for by using [JavaScriptSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();  
string json = js.Serialize(config);
```